# Is there any way to directly query the block chain for the body of a transaction given its hash?

Tags: transactions, hash

Blockchain.info provides this functionality in a simple API like so:

https://blockchain.info/rawtx/fc15f762e8dbbdd407534047ef2a9211ca0e79c3625d5fe73cdacade4f9118d6

However, I would prefer to make this query directly against the network blockchain rather than to a third party like blockchain.info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON-RPC to achieve this. The only missing information will be the **relayed_by** field.

To use the JSON-RPC API of your client edit your bitcoin.conf file like this

```
rpcuser=user 
rpcpassword=password 
rpcport=8332
server=1
```

Then you can use a library to query the API like [JSON-RPC for PHP](http://jsonrpcphp.org)

You can also do it on a much easier way by using the command line

```
./bitcoind getblock c15f762e8dbbdd407534047ef2a9211ca0e79c3625d5fe73cdacade4f9118d6
```